# What happens to AirDropped files on the iPad that do not prompt the user to open an app?

Tags: ios, ipad, file-sharing, airdrop

When I AirDrop a file to my iPad, with no app installed to open the file type, the prompt still appears on the iPad that the file is being transferred. After the transfer completes, nothing happens.

Where does the file go? Is it stored on the iPad? Is it deleted on the spot? If not, how do I locate and delete it?

Comment: what kind file type?. Now mostly files can be opened by application. Maybe you should install correct application to open file.